# Best practices for ID naming conventions in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, naming-conventions, standards

I saw this link first but it didn't seem to have much activity: [Naming convention for IDs in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909719/naming-convention-for-ids-in-android)

I am curious what the best practice is for naming IDs for the various items in Design View on Android Studio.

Right now I'm doing stuff like this: If it's an TextView with the text "Welcome To My Program", I'll name it `welcomeTextViewID`. If it's a Button that starts some subroutine called `doStuff`, I might call it `doStuffButtonID`.

In other words I use a sort of `descriptor + datatype + ID` convention.

Is this considered bad practice? I always heard mixed things on using descriptors inside the name. For example in a language like C++ naming a string variable `nameString` (since if you change the data type later you have to also update the name).

Comment: There's really no "good" or "bad" practice regarding naming your resources. It just really depends on what works for you. And you seem to have your own reasons for why to do or not do certain things, in which case I'd say follow your gut. As a java developer, I'm used to having long, descriptive names for things, and I like it that way. But some of my colleagues who are trained in javascript or C++ prefer a different style. So it really comes down to personal preference.

Comment: I don't think this is an opinion-only matter. A good naming convention improves the code readibility and mantenibility so we should stop treating this as a crazy question and start to discuss what are the elements that we should include in this names to make a better code.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Checkout --> https://github.com/umesh0492/android-guidelines

Further ID naming

IDs should be prefixed with the name of the element in lowercase underscore. For example:

```
+---------------------+
| Element   | Prefix  |
|-----------+---------+
| TextView  | text_   |
| ImageView | image_  |
| Button    | button_ |
| Menu      | menu_   |
+-----------+---------+
```

view example:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_profile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Menu example:

```
<menu>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_done"
        android:title="Done" />
```

The best guidelines I have ever seen and I do follow them.

Comment: what if the element name itself is two words, e.g. `ChipGroup`? Would you put `chip_group_` or `chipGroup_`?

Comment: @AdamBurley: I've recently come across XML component and file names declared in the internal libraries of Android Studio in **snake case** like `chipgroup_name`, `textview_name` and `edittext_name`. On the other hand, when you drag a view on an activity or fragment layout, the default name appears to be in **camel case** like `chipGroup`, `textView2` and `editText3`. [Android Handbook from Infinum](https://infinum.com/handbook/android/building-quality-apps/naming) recommends using the camel case in a **Kotlin** project and snake case for other kinds of projects.

Comment: One convenient way I find to get rid of the confusion is to go with what Android Studio suggests by default, i.e., use `editTextPhone` in the XML layout and then write `EditText phoneEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);` to reference the component in Java code.

Answer (score 12):

I follow this type of Naming convention for IDs in Android.

Ex:

```
Button : btSubmit
TextView : tvWelcome
EditText : etEmailId
CheckBox : cbHobbies
RadioButton : rbMale
LinearLayout : llPanel
```

By just looking at id you can identify your component. and use the same id   in java to avoid confusion.

Comment: I also prefer this style also because later in Java/Kotlin code I can just copy id name to make corresponding variable name and it match java's/kotlin variable naming conventions. On Kotlin when using extensions and when no need to findViewById() all the time it looks even more naturally.

Answer (score 4):

My pratice:

```
@+id/SummaryActivityName_SummaryViewType_Description
```

For example:

```
@+id/MyAct_Txv_UserName
@+id/MyAct_Grd_GridUsers
@+id/MyFrag_LstView_UserList
```

This way is much better to seek Views on a big project.
I hope it help.

Edit:
Put the same ID name on a variable name. Example:

```
private TextView MyAct_Txv_UserName;

protected void onCreate(...){
    MyAct_Txv_UserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MyAct_Txv_UserName);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I also use similar convention for XML names, e.g. `main_screen__activity`, `main_screen__content`, etc. - this way related items are grouped together. Android resources desperately need namespaces...